# Why Composer isn't updating a package to patch version?

Tags: composer-php

I have the following line in the `composer.json` `require` section.

```
"johnpbloch/wordpress-core": "^5.8"
```

Running `composer outdated` tells me, that there's an 5.8.1 update available. To my understanding the version constraint shouldn't block this version and updating to it should be possible.

For some reason running `composer update johnpbloch/wordpress-core` does nothing. The installed version stays at 5.8. `composer require johnpbloch/wordpress-core` doesn't update the package to the latest version either. Composer just keeps telling me that there's nothing to update. And I don't understand why.

I did try giving the update command the version directly, `composer update johnpbloch/wordpress-core:5.8.1`, which gave me the following error.

```
johnpbloch/wordpress 5.8.0 requires johnpbloch/wordpress-core 5.8.0 -> found johnpbloch/wordpress-core[5.8.0] 
but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^5.8, 5.8.1)
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious here, but can't see what. Hopefully someone could shed light on what could be causing this.

Here's the stripped down `composer.json` file I'm using. I left out the name and description as I don't want to share them here.

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "wecodemore/wpstarter": "~2.0",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress-core": "^5.8",
        "wpackagist-plugin/wordpress-seo": "^17.3",
        "inpsyde/wp-translation-downloader": "^2.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "public_html/content/vendor",
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "WCM\\WPStarter\\Setup::run",
        "post-update-cmd": "WCM\\WPStarter\\Setup::run",
        "wpstarter": "WCM\\WPStarter\\Setup::run"
    },
    "extra": {
        "wordpress-install-dir": "public_html/wp",
        "wordpress-content-dir": "public_html/content",
        "wpstarter": {
            "prevent-overwrite": [
                ".gitignore",
                ".htaccess",
                "wp-config.php",
                "index.php"
            ],
            "env-example": "public_html/content/vendor/wecodemore/wpstarter/wpstarter/templates/.env.example",
            "gitignore": {
                "wp": true,
                "wp-content": true,
                "vendor": true,
                "common": true,
                "custom": [
                    "*.log",
                    ".htaccess",
                    "sitemap.xml",
                    "sitemap.xml.gz"
                ]
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "public_html/content/plugins/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-plugin"
            ],
            "public_html/content/mu-plugins/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-muplugin"
            ],
            "public_html/content/themes/{$name}": [
                "type:wordpress-theme"
            ]
        },
        "wp-translation-downloader": {
            "languages": [
                "fi",
                "sv_SE"
            ],
            "directory": "public_html/content/languages"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `johnpbloch/wordpress 5.8.0 requires johnpbloch/wordpress-core 5.8.0` - that looks like a pretty obvious way to block an update

Comment: @NicoHaase But why is the `require` without any specified version also failing? Isn't it supposed to give a rat's a** about what is installed and update the package to the latest version? And I only see that error when specifying the exact version.

Comment: That might depend on whatever else you've configured. Can you share more details about your composer.json?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, I added more details to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ran:
`composer update johnpbloch/wordpress-core:5.8.1`
this results in error
`johnpbloch/wordpress 5.8.0 requires johnpbloch/wordpress-core 5.8.0`

so the answer is simple: jp/wordpress-core:5.8.1 conflicts with jp/wordpress:5.8.0 which requires explicit jp/wordpress-core:5.8.0 (not allowing any patch version updates).

To solve: run `composer update johnpbloch/wordpress-core johnpbloch/wordpress`
it will whitelist both packages for updates and resolves the newest version possible

Comment: What a glorious facepalm moment. I was stubbornly trying to update only one package and didn't consider updating both of them at the same time.